# MySQL error: Could not execute MySQL-statement: Incorrect datetime value?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

In one of my table, there are multiple column of type `TIMESTAMP`. And I have to insert the future `TIMESTAMP` in these columns. While executing a query following error has been occurred.

```
MySQL error: Could not execute MySQL-statement: Incorrect datetime value: '2060-12-22 10:35:13' for column 'goal_end_time'.
```

And in the official documentation of mysql [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) it's mentioned that it can only store upto `2038-01-19 03:14:07`.

I can not use type `DATE` since i need the time along with `DATE` too.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, but can't you just use DATETIME ? - As per the documentation it says -"The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'" . So shouldn't this suffice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by user [rocky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1173047/rocky) in comment section of this question changing my column name from `TIMESTAMP` to `DATETIME` works for me.

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary on your end to enter the value `2060-12-22 10:35:13` on your table or any future date will do? The support on the official documentation is only up to `2038-01-19 03:14:07`. I suppose it's throwing the error because in the timestamp you are using, 2060 is already way past 2038 which is the sytem's limit. If you just have to set a future date, you might want to consider something before the year 2038, like `2037-12-22 10:35:13` instead of `2060-12-22 10:35:13`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion if it is the case that the table is empty or not very very big is to export the create statements as a .sql file, rewrite them as you wish. Also do the same if you have any existing data, i.e. export insert statements (I recommend doing this in a separate file as the create statements). Finally, drop the table and execute first create statement and then inserts.

You can use for that either mysqldump command, included in your MySQL installation or you can also install MySQL Workbench, which is a free graphical tool that includes also this option in a very customizable way without having to look for specific command options.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple... find the line SQLMODE=.... in mysqld.conf (/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf) and remove NO_ZERO_DATE and NO_ZERO_IN_DATE. Import your sqlfile. and revert your changes. Don't forget to restart mysql 
`(/etc/init.d/mysql restart OR service mysql restart)`

If you cant find this line add this:

```
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```